# BigQuery documentation say only 1500 insert operations per table per day

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery Documentation saying:

> "Your project can make up to 1,500 table operations per table per day"

see here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs

I am making millions of inserts for one project for the same table. So I guess that I am missing something here, or that the documentation is wrong.
Anyone have an explanation?

**EDIT**: I am using batch jobs, not streaming

Comment: This is a ridiculous limit. GCP gives you a TB of SELECT but 1500 rows for INSERT.  Make it make sense.  10000 makes sense.  In no database universe is 10k a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is for batch jobs,  I guess you are using streaming API which does not have this limit.

Comment: I am not using streaming. I am using batch jobs.

Comment: .Jobs.Insert(c.Settings.GCloudProject, req).Media(obj.Body, googleapi.ChunkSize(chunkSize)).Context(ctx).Do()
Using this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/main/bigquery/v2/bigquery-gen.go